# Kivy font-size issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I have this button in my kivy app and I want to change it's font-size dynamically.
But when I packaged my app and ran it on other computers I noticed that the text does't fit the button as it does on my own screen.I think it's because kivy's font-size value is in pixels.
Here's the code:

```
b1 = Button(
    text=str(f.rows()[i]),
    color=(1, 1, 1),
    font_name="Comfortaa-Bold",
    background_normal="hamin.png",
    background_down="hamin.png",
    border=[0, 0, 0, 0],
)
b1.font_size = b1.width / (f.DecimalCounter() + (3 - f.DecimalCounter() // 1.5))
b1.texture_update()
self.ids.mf.add_widget(b1)
```

I really appreciate it if someone could tell me what's wrong and how it can be fixed.
Thanks guys.
P.s: It's text is a number.So it can't be fixed with breaklines using text-size. And by the way,That decimal counter the is an int number and shows how many decimals the text has.

Comment: If the text looks different on other computers, check the environment. [Controlling the environment](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html)

Comment: Anthony my man thanks a lot!!!
It workes perfeclty now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
text_size: self.size
```

and it's gonna fit in your button with any size.

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony said in the comments changing the units of font-size to dp made it work.
e.g:

```
font_size = '10dp'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to control the font size to meet some absolute size constraint in a kivy widget, you can use PIL like this:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
import numpy as np
currentfont = 'DroidSans' # or whatever font you have
teststring = 'whatever'
mydpi = 96 # or whatever your screen resolution
fontsize = 14 # starting guess
stringsize = np.array([10,10]) # large starting value, inches
maxsize = 1.1 # size constraint, inches
while stringsize[0] > maxsize: # ie check x coordinate of size for horizontal
    testfont = ImageFont.truetype(currentfont,fontsize)
    stringsize = np.array(testfont.getsize(teststring)) / mydpi
    fontsize -= 1
```